# Error in HoverRace tutorial script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the HoverRace tutorial asset package, the scripts are not attached to any game object. While doing so, it gives an error:

> can't add script behavior postprocesslayer. the scripts need to
>   derive from MonoBehavior.

Here is one of the scripts:

```
//This script handles reading inputs from the player and passing it on to the vehicle. We 
//separate the input code from the behaviour code so that we can easily swap controls 
//schemes or even implement and AI "controller". Works together with the VehicleMovement script

using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string verticalAxisName = "Vertical";        //The name of the thruster axis
    public string horizontalAxisName = "Horizontal";    //The name of the rudder axis
    public string brakingKey = "Brake";                 //The name of the brake button

    //We hide these in the inspector because we want 
    //them public but we don't want people trying to change them
    [HideInInspector] public float thruster;            //The current thruster value
    [HideInInspector] public float rudder;              //The current rudder value
    [HideInInspector] public bool isBraking;            //The current brake value

    void Update()
    {
        //If the player presses the Escape key and this is a build (not the editor), exit the game
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel") && !Application.isEditor)
            Application.Quit();

        //If a GameManager exists and the game is not active...
        if (GameManager.instance != null && !GameManager.instance.IsActiveGame())
        {
            //...set all inputs to neutral values and exit this method
            thruster = rudder = 0f;
            isBraking = false;
            return;
        }

        //Get the values of the thruster, rudder, and brake from the input class
        thruster = Input.GetAxis(verticalAxisName);
        rudder = Input.GetAxis(horizontalAxisName);
        isBraking = Input.GetButton(brakingKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once.
Make sure that the "PlayerInput" `public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour` in this line is the file name.
They need to be the same.
You can change the file name or the code line.